# How to find the solutions to the complex equation $z^3=2+i$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to find the solutions to $z^3=2+i$. But this is proving to be very difficult for me. The first solution seems to be $z=(2+1)^{1/3}$, but after that I'm lost. I tried to gather all the terms on the left side of the equation and try to factor things out so I could use the quadratic formula, but I couldn't get that to work. Then I tried replacing $z$ with $x+iy$, and that turned into an enormous mess. What's the best way to approach this problem?

Edit: I did try to get the equation into the form of $re^{i\theta}$, but $r=5^{1\over 2}$, which then leaves me with $cos\theta={2\over sqrt5}$, and $\theta$ isn't a nice number so that didn't work out for me.

Comment: Do you know about the *polar form* of complex numbers: $z=re^{it}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve this equation $z^3-(1-i)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509628/how-to-solve-this-equation-z3-1-i-0)

Comment: Yes, I do know about that, but when I tried to turn my equation into that form it didn't work out well, either. The $r$ I got was square root 5, and when I tried to find $t$ it didn't work out well and I couldn't get a solid number.

Comment: $z = \sqrt 5  e^{i \arctan \frac {1}{2}}$  is a good start.  Just because the numbers don't look "nice", does not mean that you are not on the right track.

Comment: @DougM Where did the $arctan$ come from?

Comment: You can divide any number by $3$, even one which isn't nice.

Comment: In your edit you say $\cos\theta = \frac {2}{\sqrt 5}$ and using similar logic $\sin\theta = \frac {1}{\sqrt 5}$ so $\tan \theta = \frac {\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac {1}{2}$

Comment: @DougM Wouldn't $\theta$ be $\pi n$ + $arctan{1\over 2}$ rather than $arctan{1\over 2}$ alone?

Comment: @Grace, that would indeed be the next step.  But, in order to keep the sign's straight it is  $\theta = 2\pi n + \arctan \frac 12$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Didn't get a solid number.**
Well, you cannot hope to get something "more solid" than
$$
\sqrt [6]{5} \left( \cos \left( 1/3\,\arctan \left( 1/2 \right)  \right) 
+ i\sin \left( 1/3\,\arctan \left( 1/2 \right) 
 \right) \right)
$$

Comment: you get to multiply that by $1,j,j^2$ to get all three solutions.

Answer (score 1):

use that $$z^3-a^3=(z-a)(z^2+az+a^2)$$ for $a=\sqrt[3]{2+i}$